# What speed can you go until you get ticketed?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

So I recently bought Eurotruck Simulator 2 and I noticed that though fast 60 km/h isn't great. I've gone above the speed limit but when back down in fear of a ticket. Is there an amount of km you can go above for a certain amount of time before you get ticketed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get ticketed if you're at a speed checkpoint. I usually do 100km/h on highways and when I see a warning sign slow down to 85km/h, and immediately accelerate after I'm past it.

Comment: I hope this only applies to the game :)

Comment: I drive passanger cars IRL and in my country the limit for those is 130 kmh :)